# Laravel - Group By error on query that works on phpmyadmin with results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

The query is:

```
$last_topics = Topics::orderby('date', 'DESC')->groupBy('section')->get();
```

And error:

[image]

so on error we can see query is: `select * from`topics`group by`section`order by`date`desc`

But as you can see The same query in phpMyAdmin works great, and I have my result 
[image]

So what's wrong?

I addition I can say that without groupBy in this query inside Laravel doesn't alert error, like: `$last_topics = Topics::orderby('date', 'DESC')->get();`

But as I said in phpmyadmin the same query with groupby works great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK this the mode in which your database is being used within your database config `/config/database.php`. Laravel is not adding all the columns to group by.

```
'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            // Will work for you
            'strict' => false,

            // wont work for you
            'strict' => true,
        ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `groupBy` after `get` :

```
Topics::orderby('date', 'DESC')->get()->groupBy('section');
```

It didn't work before because after calling `get()` method, you obtain an instance of `Collection` in return. Then `groupBy` method is called upon the `Collection` instead, not the `QueryBuilder` instance.

Comment: Because after calling `get()` method, you obtain an instance of `Collection` in return. Then `groupBy` method is called upon the `Collection` instead, not the `QueryBuilder` instance.